# Not able to publish a C# Project to an FTP Server - Visual Studio - ClickOnce

Tags: c#, visual-studio, publishing, auto-update, ftp-server

can someone please teach me how to publish a c# project to an FTP Server by using Visual Studio ClickOnce interface?

I've tried publishing to my home file server, and it is working just fine. (If there is an update, program detects and asks the user if they want to update.)

But the problem occurs when I try to publish to the ftp server.

Let me show you visually:

[image] 
[image]
[image]
[image]
...

.

I've tried using a "redirecting page", url-shortener, but didn't work. (The reason why I tried them was that it accepts urls with "http://" prefix.)

I also could not find any useful information at 'msdn'. 
Maybe because I did not know how to search for this (wrong keywords, etc..).

edit:

[It is uploading new versions to the FTP Server, but not reading since the URL is not working]

Additionally I do not know should I also iclude userName and Password since the directory is not accessible without them? For example:

```
ftp:// [userName] : [password] @ [ip/domainName] / [projectDirectory] /
```

Comment: Have you tried to just set `http://[ip/domain]/[project]`on the "check for updates" step (instead of `ftp://`) ?

Comment: Here is the problem: if I write "http://" instead of "ftp://", the link points to the company web-site.

Comment: It seems that the ftp url you are using is just an alias and does not reflect the real directory behind. Can you confirm ?

Comment: The link should be such that: on checking update the following file should be found `AddinABC.vsto`. For example: Application will try to find the file at `http://www.example.com/project/addin/AddinABC.vsto`. So specify the path as `http://www.example.com/project/addin/`  in **Installation Folder URL**

Comment: @DudePascalou, Yes, since it is company server, I am not able to use the actual names :) ..

Comment: @sameerkn, ".vsto" file is not generated at server. I only have following:
"projectName.application", "Setup.exe", and "Application Files" directory which includes all verions of the project and '.dll' files for each version.

Comment: @blablabla Yes, I figured that. I meant that may be the `ftp://[ip/domain]/[project]` url is an alias for another path like : `ftp://[ip/domain]/[subdirectory]/[whatever]/[project]` (that should be the same as the physical path on the server).

Comment: @DudePascalou, ohh Yes, you are right it is! :)  There are sub-directories to the project folder, but I thought that, that information won't be important, because I am having trouble with the prefix. 
By the way, please excuse my ignorance. :)

Comment: @blablabla No problem. So, if you know the "real" path, may be you should use it for the "check for updates" step.